# Ejecutar pruebas con Appium, Selenium grid desde las configuraciones de Serenity.properties

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Necesito configurar el serenity.properties para ejecutar pruebas con serenity, appium y selenium grid

Yo lo hice primero desde una clase Driver.java y me funciona bien, pero lo hago desde el serenity.properties y no me funciona

clase Driver.java driver.java class **Ejecuta Bien**

```
public class Driver {
    public static WebDriver appiumDriver() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities();

         capabilities1.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
         // capabilities1.setCapability("browserName", "Android");
         capabilities1.setCapability("platformName", "ANDROID");
         capabilities1.setCapability("udid", "341912d");
            capabilities1.setCapability("deviceName","Mi A2");
            capabilities1.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
         capabilities1.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

         WebDriver driver1 = null;
         try {
            // driver1 = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
             // driver1 = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
            // driver1 = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
            driver1 = new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return driver1;
    }

}
```

desde serenity.properties **No ejecuta**

```
webdriver.driver= appium
appium.hub = http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
appium.platformName=Android
appium.deviceName=Mi A2
appium.udid=341912d
appium.platformVersion=9.0
appium.appPackage=com.google.android.calculator
appium.appActivity=com.android.calculator2.Calculator
appium.app=
appium.browserName=appium
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: El problema era la versión de selenium grid (3.14) no era compatible con el java_client que usaba appiumdriver.